# How do I stop my C program from flooding the console with the same response

Tags: c

It was challenging to word the title for this question, but I hope you can forgive me as I will elaborate here.
The problem i'm having is my C program floods the console with "Enter the student's grade: F" if I enter anything other than an integer. I'm new to C, so I don't understand how to check if the input is of the valid type.

```
int main() {
  int grade; //number 0-10 associated with the letter grade
  while (1) {
    printf("Enter the student's grade: ");
    scanf("%i", &grade);
    switch (grade) {
      case 10: printf("A \n"); break;
      case 9: printf("A \n"); break;
      case 8: printf("B \n"); break;
      case 7: printf("C \n"); break;
      case 6: printf("D \n"); break;
      case 5: printf("F \n"); break;
      case 4: printf("F \n"); break;
      case 3: printf("F \n"); break;
      case 2: printf("F \n"); break;
      case 1: printf("F \n"); break;
      case 0: printf("F \n"); break;
      default: printf("Please enter a valid test score \n"); break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: while (1) is an infinite loop

Comment: This is scanf again:(

Comment: you mean that scanf does not wait for you to put another grade?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for interactive input. Check the return value of I/O functions!

Comment: Also you don't want to use `%i` in `scanf`. Use `%d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return of scanf. 1 means an integer was successfully scanned. 0 means the input was not an integer. Clean the input stream and try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    int grade; //number 0-10 associated with the letter grade
    int valid = 0;
    while (1) {
        do {
            printf("Enter the student's grade: ");
            if ( 1 != ( valid = scanf("%i", &grade))) {// 1 is success
                if ( EOF == valid) {
                    printf ( "found EOF\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                while ( '\n' != getchar ( )) {//clear input stream
                }
            }
        } while ( !valid);
        switch (grade) {
            case 10: printf("A \n"); break;
            case 9: printf("A \n"); break;
            case 8: printf("B \n"); break;
            case 7: printf("C \n"); break;
            case 6: printf("D \n"); break;
            case 5: printf("F \n"); break;
            case 4: printf("F \n"); break;
            case 3: printf("F \n"); break;
            case 2: printf("F \n"); break;
            case 1: printf("F \n"); break;
            case 0: printf("F \n"); break;
            default: printf("Please enter a valid test score \n"); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer (thanks to everyone else too). This definitely helps me understand how to check for what it is I was confused about!

Answer (score 2):

Check if `scanf` succeeded.

```
int nread = scanf("%i", &grade);
if (nread != 1) // scanf failed, start cleanup 
{
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
}
```

Look for any book and you'll know that `scanf` returns **number of elements that were successfully read**, so if you type a letter, it will fail to read an integer and return `0` (nothing read), then you can know there's something wrong and discard wrong stuffs.

Since `scanf` don't read anything if it encounters an error, the wrong stuff will remain in the input buffer, and badly it'll break the next `scanf`, leading to an infinite output flushing.

---

P.S. You don't need to repeat the statements after `case 5 4 3...`, just merge them into one:

```
 case 5: // Remove these and leave the last one there
 case 4:
 case 3:
 case 2:
 case 1:
 case 0: printf("F \n"); break;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: A better alternative to `gets(wastebuf)` would be `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");`